# Javascript regex match going in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, regex

this is the code I am trying :

```
var arr = [];
var str = "hey check this video out! youtube.com/watch?v=123456 and there is some other text youtube.com/watch?v=3t_3456 and some more.";
while (match = /youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^\s]+)/.exec(str)) {
  arr.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

it should capture the last part of the url's and push them to an array.

the array I am expecting is :

```
["123456", "3t_3456"]
```

but this code is going in an infinite loop, what's wrong with it ?

Comment: You have a `while` loop performing the same action over and over with nothing changing its condition. You need to modify `str` or it will just keep checking the same string over and over.

Comment: but I took the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression

Comment: @JLRishe what should be the possible solution to my problem

Answer (score 7):

The difference between your code and the page you linked to is:

- You are creating a new regex on every iteration of the loop, so it is not maintaining a record of the previous matches.
- You are not using the `g` (global) flag, so even if you were not creating new regexes, it would just keep finding the first match.

You need to reuse the same regex, and use the `g` flag:

```
var pattern = /youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^\s]+)/g;
while (match = pattern.exec(str)) {
    arr.push(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33016026/380733 sometimes you need an extra condition as explained there

Answer (score 2):

You are inviting an infinite loop without using the global flag in your regex.

```
var arr = [];
var str = "hey check this video out! youtube.com/watch?v=123456 and there is some other text youtube.com/watch?v=3t_3456 and some more.";
var re = /youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^\s]+)/g;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  arr.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pHbvp/).

Without the `g` flag you'd run into an infinite loop, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pHbvp/1/) (**WARNING:** Clicking this link may crash your browser.).