# Regex exec() loop never terminates in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, infinite-loop

```js
var matches;

while(matches = /./g.exec("abc"))
{
    console.log("hey");
}
```

This never terminates. I expect it to terminate after 3 loops.

Warning: Don't run it in Chrome because the infinite log lines freeze your entire system. It's safe to run it in IE (it still freezes your webpage but you can go to the location bar and press enter to reload).

Comment: `matches = /./g.exec("abc")` will return ['a'] which is a truthy value in JS, hence it runs into an infinite loop. It's like `while(true){ // dosomething } `. As the condition evaluates to true in every iteration, it will never break

Comment: @Arkantos When you use the `g` flag, each iteration is supposed to start where the previous one ended.

Comment: @Barmar, but, as you use a regexp literal in the test part of the loop, it will create a regexp each time you want the test, and compile it, and execute it on the string `"abc"` with a fresh regexp each time.  For sure this is not what was intended, but you have to observe where the regexp is created and compiled.  Even if javascript optimices this to create and compile the regexp only once, the matching status or history must be renewed each time you go through the test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you should execute `exec` in a loop:

```
var matches;        
var re = /./g;

while(matches = re.exec("abc")) {
  if (matches.index === re.lastIndex)
     re.lastIndex++;
  console.log("hey");
}
```

- Keep regex in a separate variable rather than using regex literal.
- Also if `lastIndex` (matched position) of regex is same as `index` property of resulting array then increment `lastIndex` by 1.

Comment: You only need to do the increment if you're using a regexp that can match a zero-length string.

Comment: Thanks. Keeping it in a separate variable was the solution. However I don't understand, why do I need to increment `lastIndex`? exec() does that for me.

Comment: @StefanMonov It will put it past the end of the last match. But if the regexp can match a zero-length string, it will get stuck at that point and keep matching that same empty string.

Comment: @Barmar I had this problem. Changing my RE to no longer match empty strings worked a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's because you are creating a new object with the `g` flag every time, instead of keeping one regex object. The regex object keeps track of the last match. Since you are creating new objects every time, the object starts from the beginning.

Each regex literal is it's own object that's why:

```
/./g !== /./g
```